# Downgrading PHP Version 8.1 to 7.4 LAMP instance in AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, lamp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I created a LAMP(PHP 8) instance on AWS Lightsail. My PHP version is v8.1.16. However, I need version v7.4 now.

How can I downgrade v8.1 to v7.4? Should I recreate the instance with v7.4?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Bitnami has discontinued their version of PHP 7.4. However, I have been able to downgrade to PHP 7.4 by following these steps:

1. stop services and backup the actual PHP stack:

   ```
   sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
   sudo mv /opt/bitnami /opt/bitnami.backup
   ```
2. download and copy in your vps the Stack PHP 7.4 version (this is in my repo, fell free to download and save for upload to your own cloud). You could copy this file by FTP.

   ```
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/185AOnsC-fF_luyWYT0dKVNdZpopN5XEA/view
   ```
3. Once you have this file on the server, you must grant it execution permissions:

   ```
   chmod +x bitnami-lampstack-7.4.1-1-dev-linux-x64-installer.run
   ```
4. execute the file for install:

   ```
   ./bitnami-lampstack-7.4.1-1-dev-linux-x64-installer.run
   ```
5. The installer wizard asks which packages you want to install; Laravel, cake, etc.
6. Then the wizard will ask you in which folder you want to install, there you must put `/opt/bitnami`
7. Finally you will see this message:

> Setup has finished installing Bitnami LAMP Stack on your computer.
>
> Launch Bitnami LAMP Stack [Y/n]:

image LAMP source:
https://linux.softpedia.com/get/Internet/BitNami/BitNami-LAMPStack-32288.shtml